# mysql - Error 1064

Tags: mysql

I have a problem with MySQL.

I had successfully set up MySQL, as well as created a database (named "Users").
I am able to `CREATE DATABASE` (such as the one named "Users"), but when I'm onto creating tables using the command `CREATE TABLE`, MySQL returns the statement:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, password NOT NULL)' at line 2

Here's my code:

```
-- First, I'll set the database to "Users":
USE users

-- Then, I'll make a table within the database Users:
CREATE TABLE users (
  user NOT NULL,
  password NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You are missing the data type. Varchar, int, char, .... [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

Comment: Okay, thanks for that answers!  But, which answer should I accept?

Comment: The fastest person to post the correct answer @sachinsarawgi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your syntax for creating a table in `MySQL` is not correct. You have to provide the data type for every `column` you create inside a `table`, Like if your user and password is `varchar` type then:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
);
```

Also read [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html) for reference.

Comment: @Lloyd can this answer be accepted, if it really helped you. In this way it will help other users in understanding that the problem is solved. :)

Answer (score 1):

You miss the data type for your columns, try this one (obviously you can change the column type as for your requirements):

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  user     VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
  password VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL
);
```